# Unity plaform rotation controlled by accelerometer rotates in wrong direction when phone is upside down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, accelerometer

I am developing a Unity game where you control the rotation of a platform using the phone accelerometer. Everything works great when holding the phone in front of me, but if I lay down in my bed with the phone above me (upside down) and tilts the phone forward or backward the platform rotates in the opposite direction. How can I solve this? Maybe I need to invert the direction of the input if the phone is upside down in some way, I am not sure.

Here is my script that is added to the platform object.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class PlatformAccelerometer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float maxTiltAngle = 45;
    [SerializeField]
    private float viewAngle = 25;
    [SerializeField]
    private float tiltSpeed = 10;

    private Quaternion _target;

    private void Update()
    {
        var tiltAroundX = Input.acceleration.y * maxTiltAngle + viewAngle;
        var tiltAroundZ = -Input.acceleration.x * maxTiltAngle;
        _target = Quaternion.Euler(tiltAroundX, 0, tiltAroundZ);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, _target, Time.deltaTime * tiltSpeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you may have answered your own question, are you just not sure how to implement it?

Comment: @toobladink In that case, nice! :) And yes, I would be very happy to get help implementing that.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I don't know much on this topic and I'm not sure I can provide a solution. But, are you not able to detect when the phone is upside down, and then apply different logic? I'm not sure when the phone may be "upside down" or if there is even a sensor that could detect change in that direction.